# How to disable reapte concat in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add to my description "VIP" only if i dont "VIP" contain alreay in my description
input :
"Down"
output

```
"**VIP** Down"
```

but all i get is

```
"VIP VIP VIP VIP VIP Down" infiny VIP addtion
```

here is my code:

```
update customer set Description =('VIP' + '  ' +Description) where Description NOT LIKE '%VIP%' and Importent = 15;
```

Any idea why?

Comment: `+` adds integers in MySQL.  What database are you really using?  Tag appropriately.

Comment: why "websphere" tag? (now deleted)

Comment: sry it was a mistake

Comment: Please edit your question and remove unnecessary tags and clean up spelling.

Comment: Use `CONCAT('VIP', '  ', Description)` instead of `'VIP' + '  ' +Description`

Comment: its not working for IBM OMNIBUS DB

Comment: nevet mid i just add a new field and fix it